# Android facebook like using webview

Tags: android, facebook, webview, facebook-like

I use the following code to load a facebook like button inside a webview.

```
            likeWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
            likeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

            url ="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?" +
            "href=" + URLEncoder.encode( "http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/" )
            + "&" +
            "layout=button_count&" +
            "show_faces=0&" +
            "width=90&" +
            "height=24&" +
            "locale=en_IN" +
            "colorscheme=light" ;

            likeWebView.loadUrl( url );
```

the problem is when the user is signing in the process redirects him to a blank page,
how do i intercept this webview request and cancel this action/close webview ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually use a WebViewClient's shouldOverrideUrlLoading method in this case.

```
likeWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
likeWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

likeWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading (WebView view, String url) {
        if(url.contains("something")) return true;
        return false; //Default is to not override unless our condition is met.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class WebViewPreLoad extends WebView{
public WebViewPreLoad(Context context) {
       super(context);
}
    public void loadUrl(String str){
    if(str.contains("something"))
            super.loadUrl(str);
        else 
                     hide this
    }
}
```

of course you will have to find the correct "if" for ur case

also, do the same thing with

```
 public void loadUrl(String url, Map<String,String> extraHeaders)
```

change the super statement to:

```
super.loadUrl(url, extraHeaders);
```